# Power Automate Approval Workflow Triggered by "When an Item is Created" is kicking off two simultaneous workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a workflow that is triggered when someone uploads a SharePoint file to a library ("When an Item is Created"). Sometimes this workflow is kicking off a duplicate workflow for the same file, about 30 seconds after the first. Any ideas why there would be duplicate workflow? Is the second one kicked off because there are "required" columns, and the user is filling in those fields on the upload.aspx page and then pressing "check in" to trigger another workflow?

Comment: That *should* only be true if you are using the "When an Item is Created **or Modified**" trigger.  If you are definitely using the item created trigger, it should only ever be fired once per item no matter how many changes are made to it after initial create.

Comment: I know, it's weird. The trigger is definitely "When an Item is Created" only. I checked the two instances' trigger details that ran. One instance doesn't have any metadata fields filled in (Amount, Office, etc). The other one has metadata fields filled in. There's one column marked required, which sets the file to checked out status upon uploading and once required metadata is filled in on the upload dialog page, the user hits the Check In button and the file is updated. I think that sometimes the workflow is trigger when the doc is initially uploaded, and again once metadata is filled in.

Comment: @aoe2 Can you share detailed configuration (actions) for the flow? I’ve tested with a required column and “Require Check-Out” feature on in the document library. The action I use is "Start and wait for an approval". If I add a “Update file properties” action, it will force to fill in the required field and then the file will remain checked out in the library.
The issue might be related to your flow actions. Or you can turn off the flow and build a new one with simplified procedure, see if you can reproduce this issue with the new one.